# How to build with maven inside docker container using dependency on a docker image?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, maven, docker-image

I have 2 spring boot projects, one of them is the "core" which is used as a dependency by the second, called here "sascar".

I have a Dockerfile to generate the core image:

```
FROM maven:3.3-jdk-8
 
WORKDIR /opt/ivr-engine-core
 
ADD ./engine-core/. /opt/engine-core
 
RUN ls -la /opt/engine-core
 
RUN mvn clean install
```

Then I run to build the image:

```
docker build . -t engine-core
```

Then I start a docker container with the image just created using the main project (engine-sascar inside the app folder) and enter in the bash:

```
docker run -it --rm -w /app -v "$PWD/engine-sascar:/app" engine-core:latest bash
```

When inside the container I try to run the maven command to package or install, the point is, this main project can´t reach the core project to use its classes:

```
mvn clean package
```

Resulting in:

```
[INFO] Compiling 35 source files to /app/target/classes
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] /app/src/main/java/com/app/sascar/StepOne.java:[8,33] package com.engine.core does not exist
```

How could I make this maven project inside this container "see" those classes inside the image I created before?

Comment: You need to expose the dependencies in a central repository. You cannot use dependencies from inside one container in another container.

Comment: @M.Deinum do you have any suggestion how I would do that? Just for clarifying, there will be a lot of applications that will need to be build using that "core" dependency, this one I mentioned is just the first one I am testing. BTW thanks for responding.

Comment: How to do what? You should have a centralized maven repository (like JFrog) in your company which will hold your artifacts, your builds should publish artifacts to there. That way others can re-use existing artifacts. It isn't any different from not using docker, you are just macking it overly complex with docker (for these simple builds imho).

Comment: It´s because all those builds will be done on a pipeline.

Comment: Still doesn't matter you need a centralized repository, with or without a pipeline.